# OneSignal In App Messaging always display full screen dialog in android

Tags: android, kotlin, onesignal

Get full-screen dialog when firing In-App message in android, I also set the center view in one signal console, is anyone have any idea about this problem?

OneSignal setUp:
[image]

Get Notifications in android devices like this:
[image]

Is there any problem with one signal?